# recycler views both horizontal ans vertical scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I need both horizontal scrolling and vertical scrolling. how can be it possible using recycler views, or should i use 2 way views? Any one help me please.
How will set the adapter for the same?

Comment: I think your question is somewhat unclear, are you asking about a view that changes based on a layout which switches between scrolling vertically OR horizontally? or are you referring to a ViewPager with a vertical list for each tab? or are you talking about a vertical list containing horizontally scrolling cells (like the Play Store has)? please be more clear so whoever is answering won't be guessing what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

you can add recycler view to your layout file

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

In java file set its orientation to horizontal or vertical

```
LinearLayoutManager LayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
LayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);// or LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL
RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager);
```

Comment: I doubt that this is the solution for the original answer, user needs BOTH scrolling methods. So I'd say that user needs ViewPager + RecyclerView combination.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use two times same adapter one for HORIZONTAL and second for VERTICAL.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

Use above in XML file two times one for HORIZONTAL and one for VERTICAL

This for HORIZONTAL

```
LinearLayoutManager LayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
LayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL); 
RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager);
OrderedDetailsAdapter orderedDetailsAdapter;
orderedDetailsAdapter = new OrderedDetailsAdapter(OrderDetailsActivity.this,    orderDetailsPojo.getOrderItemsList());mOrderDetailsRecyclerView.setAdapter(orderedDetailsAdapter);
```

This for VERTICAL

```
LinearLayoutManager LayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
LayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL); 
RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager);
OrderedDetailsAdapter orderedDetailsAdapter;
orderedDetailsAdapter = new OrderedDetailsAdapter(OrderDetailsActivity.this,    orderDetailsPojo.getOrderItemsList());mOrderDetailsRecyclerView.setAdapter(orderedDetailsAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add your Vertical-LinearLayout recyclerView inside HorizontalScrollView :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/nested"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

For vertical recyclerview add these lines:

```
  LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```